# Windows 10 unable detect the Python Environment Variable

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables

Previously I used Python 3.6.8 version . I uninstall python removed environment variable, and
**re-installed the same version and set the Environment variable Manually**. But now when I run **python --version** in cmd is not displaying any error and points to a new line as follows.

**C:\Users\User>python --version

C:\Users\User>**

When I set path it not gives any issue.

C:\Users\User>set path="C:\dir1\dir"
C:\Users\User>python --version
Python 3.6.8
C:\Users\User>

I need to resolve this by setting environment variable.

Additionally pycharm can detect python.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directory to the path for all future terminals (including cmd) by:

1. Open "System Properties" - how you do this depends on your windows version, on Win 10 you click the settings icon and type "environment" into the search bar and it'll give you the right option.
2. Go to the "Advanced" tab
3. At the bottom there is a button for "Environment Variables".  Click that.
4. In the "System Variables" window, highlight the "Path" variable and click the "Edit" button.
5. Now click "New" and add the directory that you've been adding manually.

You will need to start a new terminal as this does not update the path for currently open terminals.

Also note: "python --version" isn't looking for an environment variable, it's running the python.exe with the "--version" option (which, of course, reports the version).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I tried manually adding the variable (mentioned in the question) . And automatically using python installer both methods are not effective.

Comment: When you open a cmd terminal, before doing anything else, and type "path", does that have the directory that contains python.exe?

Comment: Yes it contains.

Comment: Alright, before you change the path, try "whereis python", then set the path like you do above and try "whereis python" again.  Is there a difference?

Comment: No any difference.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Thank you for the contribution.

Comment: The registry, eh?  I feel your pain.  At least it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. I cleaned the registry using CCleaner and reinstalled the python version as a fresh installation. Now it Works properly.